# How do you incorporate Node.js/passport into my website?

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I'm new to webdev and I'm trying to use passport for registration/authentication on a site I'm setting up. I'm also going to write an application in node later on that will be using some of the user data (users will need to provide an API key for an account on another site that I will use to pull data into the application).

At the moment, the main issue I'm having is figuring out what goes where. I've found plenty of resources that explain how to create an app using passport, but nothing shows how it would be incorporated into your website or where the files should be in relation to your website. I'm relatively new to Node.js, and while I've written a few small applications I have never hosted them anywhere.

Bonus question: I'm using MongoDB with passport and I was also planning to use it to store some JSON my application will be receiving from API calls. However, I wanted to use MySQL to store some data as well. More specifically, I'm planning to save the raw JSON then I'll create a relational database out of the data I need from the JSON and then keep the rest in MongoDB for easy access. Is this common/smart, or should I focus on keeping everything in my MongoDB? I'm relatively new to NoSQL.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would reference this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local). I just recently used this to help myself with a new application.  Also there is an example of the same thing but in SQL [here](https://gist.github.com/manjeshpv/84446e6aa5b3689e8b84).  So not sure what you mean by " where the files should be in relation to your website". The information related to to authentication should go in your database.

To your "bonus question" you can use two databases.  The key here is to ask yourself why and what are the true needs for data, and how is this data accessed and used.  From ground up I would like one and stick with it. If at some point later you realize a certain type of data would be better in a different database then you can add it.

Side note: look into an IDE such as [webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) to help you out.